# Error despite Global keyword being used to access variable inside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scope, global-variables

I have created few global variables as shown in my code below. However when I try to use them inside the individual functions, I still get the same error.

Please find my code below

```
def create_df():
  global sheet_name, sheet_df 
  for s in sheets:
     sheet_name = s
     sheet_df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=s)
     sheet_df = sheet_df[sheet_df.columns.difference(sheet_df.filter(like='Derived').columns,sort=False)]
     print("Sheet " + str(s) + " is created as a dataframe successfully")
     transform_stage_1_df()

def transform_stage_1_df():
    global sheet_df 
    sheet_df = pd.melt(sheet_df, id_vars='subject_ID', var_name='headers', value_name='dates')
    sheet_df['header_extracted'] = [x.split("Date")[0] for x in sheet_df['headers']]
    sheet_df['day'] = sheet_df['header_extracted'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True).astype(int)
    sheet_df = sheet_df[sheet_df.groupby(['subject_ID','header_extracted'])['dates'].transform('count').ne(0)].copy()
    sheet_df = sheet_df.sort_values(by=['subject_ID','day'])
    sheet_df.drop(['header_extracted', 'day'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print("Stage 1 transformation is complete")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Execution Started")
    print("File read successfully")
    sheets = xls.sheet_names
    sheet_name = sheet_df = Non_Cholesterol = None
    dataFramesDict = dict()
    create_df()
    add_units()
    Non_Cholesterol.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

Based on SO posts, I have already updated the global keyword but still I get the `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sheet_df' referenced before assignment`

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-210-dc2f8412235d> in <module>
      7     sheet_df = None
       8     dataFramesDict = dict()
  ----> 9     create_df()
 10     Non_Cholesterol.to_csv('C:\\Users' + 
 str('Non_cholesterol.csv'),index=None)
 11     print("Export successful")

 <ipython-input-205-c93604f0da4f> in create_df()
  5         sheet_df =sheet_df[sheet_df.columns.difference(sheet_df.filter(like='Derived').columns,sort=False)]
  6         print("Sheet " + str(s) + " is created as a dataframe 
  successfully")
     ----> 7         transform_stage_1_df()

 <ipython-input-206-b59c70018a9b> in transform_stage_1_df()
  1 def transform_stage_1_df():
  ----> 2     sheet_df = pd.melt(sheet_df, id_vars='subject_ID', 
 var_name='headers', value_name='dates')
  3     sheet_df['header_extracted'] = [x.split("Date")[0] for x in 
 sheet_df['headers']]
  4     sheet_df['day'] = sheet_df['header_extracted'].str.extract('(\d+)', 
 expand=True).astype(int)
  5     sheet_df = 
 sheet_df[sheet_df.groupby(['subject_ID','header_extracted']) 
 ['dates'].transform('count').ne(0)].copy()

  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sheet_df' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: you put the global in the wrong place, you need to do the global in the functions

Comment: You mean whereever I use the variable, I have to use `global` everywhere? I mean once in whichever function it is being used?

Comment: once at the top of each function declare the variables you want to survive as global. i want to point out that this is a pretty bad programming practice and unless you have some extremely specific need, don't do this

Comment: No, still its the same error. Please see the updated code

Comment: @Nullman - Is using `Global` a bad programming practice? Or the way I have written code in general?

Comment: I am new to Python and willing to hear your comments/suggestions to improve

Comment: little bit of both. generally try to avoid using globals because that will very quickly make code unmaintainable. have your functions return what ever it is they changed, or pass mutables for them to change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197343/discussion-between-avles-and-nullman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the variables at the body of your script. When you say `global variable_name` it means that you will be accessing the variable outside of the function instead of a local variable named `variable_name`.

```py
# Initialize the variables first
sheet_name = None
sheet_df = None

def create_df():
  global sheet_name, sheet_df 
  for s in sheets:
     sheet_name = s
     sheet_df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=s)
     sheet_df = sheet_df[sheet_df.columns.difference(sheet_df.filter(like='Derived').columns,sort=False)]
     print("Sheet " + str(s) + " is created as a dataframe successfully")
     transform_stage_1_df()

def transform_stage_1_df():
    global sheet_df 
    sheet_df = pd.melt(sheet_df, id_vars='subject_ID', var_name='headers', value_name='dates')
    sheet_df['header_extracted'] = [x.split("Date")[0] for x in sheet_df['headers']]
    sheet_df['day'] = sheet_df['header_extracted'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True).astype(int)
    sheet_df = sheet_df[sheet_df.groupby(['subject_ID','header_extracted'])['dates'].transform('count').ne(0)].copy()
    sheet_df = sheet_df.sort_values(by=['subject_ID','day'])
    sheet_df.drop(['header_extracted', 'day'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    print("Stage 1 transformation is complete")


if __name__ == '__main__':
   print("Execution Started")
   xls = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\All.xlsx')
   print("File read successfully")
   sheets = xls.sheet_names
   dataFramesDict = dict()
   create_df()
```

Comment: Can you comment the full error and which line it throws? I can not access the image sadly.

Comment: Updated now. please check

Comment: It is supposed to work, if its stated like that. I thought you might be calling a function that contains code for main. Mistake on my part.